# Reading CPU temperature

Tags: linux, cpu, i2c, temperature

I have used

> lm-sensors

in one of my board to read temperature parameters. For that, i had to enable I2C in my kernel. But i am having some complications with some other part of my board after enabling my i2c, which i am not going to bore you with. 
Is there any possibility to get these values without having to enable i2c ? I did my own small research on this and i couldn't find anything. 
Any guidance in this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The sensors are usually located in a chip called SuperIO (for laptops this may be integrated partly into the Embedded Controller with the satellite sensors left around). This chip is attached to the PCH through an I2C bus, LPC bus, UART or GPIO with the former being usually majorly thanks to its standardization. If your sensors are behind an I2C bus, you need to enable it unless you want to write a rogue LKM that drive it autonomously. However, I2C support should not cause major issues in Linux, maybe you are better off fixing them?

Comment: I guess i will directly access the registers and see what i can do.